# ie9 and less stretching absolute input field bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, position

Can't seem to stretch (using top,left,right or bottom css rules) of an absolute input field in **ie9.** Let alone **ie8** or **ie7**.

http://jsfiddle.net/global_1981/Y6pEj/

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6pEj/10/)***

Hi now u can **change your code** if possible and add `label tag` in your form **don't** used `position`

as like this

***html***

```
<h1>Testing ie input field, absolutely positioned to fill container</h1>
<div class="container">
    <label><input class="field" type="text" /></label>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.container {
  background-color:green;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
}
label{
margin:5px;
    display:block;
}
.field {
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6pEj/10/)***